# Android:Assigning ip address to my android device

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, ip

i am making the application in which i have to assign my own ip address to the android device which will be used for the udp connection...is it possible to do so..i know that WIFI_STATIC_IP can be used 
to set the ip ..will this ip be useful in the socket connection??

any type of help will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but this might not be possible in android.

Comment: ok then i have to find some other way to do this

Comment: Why in the name of $DEITY do you want to set programmatically from Java a specific IP address for the device? Is it simply for debugging?

Comment: no it is the requirement of the application